# Assign small dataframe to large dataframe by row indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to assign a small dataframe to a large dataframe, both have the same columns.
I couldn't find a duplicate on this.

Pandas version 1.1.4 which I can't upgrade right now because of IT reasons.

My failed attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": np.arange(10),
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": np.arange(5),
})

df1.iloc[3:3+len(df2)] = df2

print(df1)
```

prints

```
     a
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  3.0
4  4.0
5  NaN
6  NaN
7  NaN
8  8.0
9  9.0
```

Required:

```
     a
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  0.0
4  1.0
5  2.0
6  3.0
7  4.0
8  8.0
9  9.0
```

Please notice there is a single column in the example, but really there will be many, and I don't want to specify any of them.

How can I accomplish that in the way pandas meant it to happen?

Also, what happened in my attempt?

Comment: I cannot replicate. Running your code produces required output.

Comment: Likewise. Please make sure that this is reproducible in a new environment, or provide an updated example.

Comment: I just tried again by copying from the question and getting the `nan`s again. How can this be different?

Comment: Pandas version 1.1.4

Comment: try `df1.iloc[3:3+len(df2)]=df2.values` is  it working?

Comment: @AnuragDabas it does work with `.values`. Very strange that it doesn't work without it for me and does for others.

Comment: maybe because of your pandas version

Comment: @AnuragDabas What is your version?

Comment: maybe because of your pandas version...it's working in version `'1.2.4'`

Comment: I suspect a conflict between the indexes of the two dataframes.

Comment: It is because you are trying to set values on  index `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` from `df1` with index `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` of `df2`. Pandas always aligns on index and thus it is matching index from df2 and putting those values in df1, for the non matched index, it sets NaN. If you wish to ignore the index and set the values, you can use `.values` or `.to_numpy()` as shown in the answer by Anurag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try `values` attribute or `to_numpy()` method:

```
df1.iloc[3:3+len(df2)]=df2.values
#OR
#df1.iloc[3:3+len(df2)]=df2.to_numpy()
```

**Update:**

other way:

```
df1.iloc[3:3+len(df2)]=df2.set_index(df1.iloc[3:3+len(df2)].index)
```

output of df1:

```
    a
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   0
4   1
5   2
6   3
7   4
8   8
9   9
```

Comment: The reason I don't like this solution is it depends on the order of the columns. If I have 100 columns, I have to make sure the order is correct, and fix it if it isn't. I would like something more built in. Is it possible in 1.1.4?

Comment: @Gulzar sir kindly chek update...updated answer **:)**

Comment: ugly but works :) thanks. Is there a way to extract the `3:3+len(df2)` part into a variable?

Comment: @FehmiElicebinde I said you can't store `3:3+len(df2)` into a variable and why Gulzar code dind't work is explained  in the comments If you read the comments in question you will find out...thanks for giving feedback... **:)**

Comment: @Gulzar you can store it like that `i=slice(3,3+len(df2))`

Comment: @Gulzar you could also use `np.r_` if you wish to put this under a variable: `np.r_[3:3+len(df2)]` not sure if that is what you might want but you can play around with it